# What does @ mean above a function in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, function, callback, raspberry-pi

I was looking through some example code for the skywriter HAT. In there example code, they have this:

```
@skywriter.move()
def move(x, y, z):
    print( x, y, z )
```

What does the @ mean above the function? Does it mean whenever `skywriter.move()` is called it executes `move()` passing the parameters `x`, `y`, and `z` that was returned from `skywriter.move()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a decorator...basically a wrapper that changes the behavior of the function in some way.  For more info google "python decorators".

Some good info here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Comment: So they add extra functionality to functions? So like `@staticmethod` makes the function static?

Comment: So in this case, it's basically passing `move(x, y, z)` to `skywriter.move()`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with skywriter, so I can't tell you what that decorator is doing.  But decorators are just more python code, so you should be able to find the code or some documentation that would give you a better idea.

Comment: Skywriter is for a raspberry pi HAT that senses finger taps, swipes, etc. I'm guessing it calls it when that happens.